# How do I uncheck radiobutton if another is checked?

Tags: java

I am using a content pane with gridbag layout and i have created 3 `JRadioButtons`.  I have an `actionlistener` that makes a command when they are press and in a different method I handle the actions.

I tried `buttonname.setSelected(false);` and it does not work.  I searched about this and people were talking about button groups so I created one and added the buttons to the group like this:

```
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(color1);
    group.add(color2);
    group.add(color3);
```

I put that in my pane thing where I add components to pane after I added the buttons with `pane.add(buttonname, c);`

How do I `group.clearSelection()` or whatever the command is from my action handling method?

Answer (score 2):

This is from the Javadocs of ButtonGroup

> This class is used to create a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of
>   buttons. Creating a set of buttons with the same ButtonGroup object
>   means that turning "on" one of those buttons turns off all other
>   buttons in the group. A ButtonGroup can be used with any set of
>   objects that inherit from AbstractButton.

So it would seem that you do not need to do anything.